# How do I enable agda-mode's unicode input mode across all modes in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, unicode

I'd like to be able to type unicode characters like Π using agda-mode's "\Pi". In Emacs, I used to configure this like:

```
(load-file (let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8))
                (shell-command-to-string "agda-mode locate")))
(require 'agda-input); for unicode input via latex names like \forall.
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook (lambda () (set-input-method "Agda")))
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook (lambda () (set-input-method nil)))
```

In Spacemacs, I've enabled the `agda` layer (which has nicely found my Homebrew agda installation without addition configuration, thanks). I am able to type "\Pi" in `.agda` files an it works. However, it is not available in other modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the hooks to the `dotspacemacs/user-config` function seems work.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration.
This is the place where most of your configurations should be done. Unless it is
explicitly specified that a variable should be set before a package is loaded,
you should place your code here."
  (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook (lambda () (set-input-method "Agda")))
  (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook (lambda () (set-input-method nil)))
  )
```

Let me know if there's a better way.

Comment: If this resolves the problem, please accept your own answer so we can mark the question as answered.

Comment: I am not using spacemacs but this solution worked for me. I had to add `(require 'agda-input)` before the two `add-hook` lines though.